# Symfony CLI doesn't export docker desktop vars

Tags: docker, macos, symfony, symfony-cli

I'm on mac (Apple chip), and I'm trying to create a Symfony project using Symfony CLI & Docker.

```
$ symfony create new_project
$ cd new_project
$ symfony composer require orm
```

It install Symfony, Doctrine, and ask me to create `docker-compose.yml`.

Perfect.

I can even launch `docker-compose up --build` and I can see the container being build & launched on my Docker Desktop application.

But when I launch my symfony server, I'm unable to connect to the database.

As I read, I try the command `symfony var:export -vv` and then, I can see than none of the docker variables are automatically exported. And I can see, thanks to the `-vv` option, this silent error :

`WARNING   symfony  Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I looked at this error and I try `docker-machine ls`. I can see that there is no docker-machine working on my computer, even if my Docker Desktop says otherwhise.

How can I make Docker Desktop & Symfony CLI works together ? Why `docker-image` and Docker Desktop doesn't communicate ?

When I look to the Docker Desktop documentation, they mention that the Docker Desktop provide the docker API through `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` but mine seams not working.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Please show your `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-machine` is a legacy software for OSX. Uninstall it and install the latest version of docker using the command `brew install --cask docker` and then try the same steps as before.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot !

I went to Docker Desktop > Troubleshooting > Uninstall.

Then, I uninstalled `docker-machine` from brew : `$ brew uninstall docker-machine`.

Finally, I reinstalled every thing via brew : `$ brew install --cask docker`

And it worked !